# How should I go about computing the 30-day model free implied volatility (MFIV) daily?

Tags: options, option-pricing, volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility

As the title suggests, how can I calculate the MFIV daily (for a market index)? My MFIV follows the procedure described in DeMiguel et al. (2013) *Improving Portfolio Selection Using Option-Implied Volatility and Skewness*. A brief recap of the MFIV procedure is as follows:

1. Obtain OTM call and puts with deltas <0.5 and >-0.5, respectively.
2. Using their implied volatilities, perform a cubic spline for the volatility skew using the moneyness range of 1/3 to 3 with 1001 points in between.
3. Price 1001 options using the Black-Scholes formula.
4. Price the variance contract using the formula from Bakshi et al. (2003) *Stock Return Characteristics, Skew Laws, and the Differential Pricing of Individual Equity Options*.
5. Take the root of the variance contract that is the MFIV.

My question is - If we should use a 30-day set of OTM call and put options to compute a single 30-day MFIV measure, how can we go about computing this daily if there aren't 30-day TTM options everyday?

From what I understand, one can interpolate for a 30-day IV daily using "surrounding" contracts [How to compute 30/60/90-day Implied Volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27714/how-to-compute-30-60-90-day-implied-volatility) but these only produce a single 30-day IV.

**How can I go about generating these multiple 30-day OTM call and put options on the days that they don't exist?** Since options usually exist for a fixed maturity - like the 3rd Friday of every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read carefully their paper they are not using the raw options data from OptionMetrics but the smoothed surface file:

> We use the volatility surface file, which contains a smoothed implied-
> volatility surface for a range of standard maturities and a set of
> option delta points. From the surface file we select the
> out-of-the-money implied volatilities for calls and puts (we take
> implied volatilities for calls with deltas smaller than or equal to
> 0.5, and implied volatilities for puts with deltas bigger than -0.5) for a maturity of 30 days.

This surface file interpolation to have a standard grid on strikes and maturity.

Comment: Wow, that's fast, that might be the answer to my question. Let me check with the OptionMetrics smoothed IV surface source :)

Comment: Thanks @phdstudent , one last question - Is the MFIV computed from 30-day options of monthly or annual frequency?

Comment: Sorry unsure if I understand the question.

Comment: When you compute the MFIV from the square root of the variance contract (which is computed using the volatility skew of 30-day options), is it of monthly or annual frequency? For example, when one computes the standard deviation of a 21 day historical rolling window of returns, one gets daily volatility and we multiply it by 252^0.5 to get annual volatility. If we multiply it by 21^0.5, we get monthly volatility instead.